# How to prevent firefox from keep loading new content while scrolling to the page bottom

Tags: firefox, autoload, preferences, autoscroll, overscroll

How to prevent firefox from keep loading new content while scrolling to the page bottom? I've met this at the news sites, various media resources and even at google search.

I switched off autoscroll at browser preferences, it didn't help. Then I switched off the layout.css.overscroll-behavior.enabled and apz.overscroll.enabled at about:config, it seems to have helped a little bit, because pages stop to deploy so intensively, but they keep load new content when page is scrolled to the bottom. I don't need it and I want to leaf google search results page by page without bottom autoload.

Comment: you can try disabling javascript for the page

Comment: Thanks, it worked but it may alter the page disabling the display of some elements and even pictures. Is there some more specific way?